# In react, when the route path is different, but same component. How can I prevent re-mounting?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux

In react router (v2), when there is different route path, but same component.

How can we prevent remount the component, for example, unmounts the component and then mounts the component again.

It causes calling componentDidMount twice.

When there are some subscribe request, then my app will subscribe twice.

So the subscribed event will be called twice.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Just nest your react-router code. Like below,

```
  <Route component={Home}>
    <IndexRoute />
    <Route path="/" />
    <Route path="/market" />
  </Route>
```

Just define parent  tag with the component which you want to call once, and define child  tag only with the path.

Then if route path changes '/' to '/market' will not remount the component.

Below code is remounting scenario which you might don't want.

...

```
<Route component={Home} path="/" />
<Route component={Home} path="/trade" />
```

...